# HTML & CSS - How to show a .SVG but let end-users click and copy a .PNG when clicking and dragging away (or copying in general)

Tags: html, css, image, graphics

Imagine you have an image in two versions, one being a .SVG and another one being a .PNG version.

You show the .SVG on a webpage, but when end-users click and drag that image for example into their social media app, you would like them to have copied the .PNG version instead of the .SVG version (since, some of those media apps can't handle .SVGs).

Using only HTML and CSS, is this possible? Many thanks for your help.

Could the same answer be extended to also work when the end-user would copy the presented image in another way (such as through mouse-interaction, by selecting the visible image and then copying through keyboard shortcuts or menu mouse-navigation)?

Comment: it might be, if you positioned the png over the visible one on the page, set it to be transparent, then when the mouse grabbed it, it would be grabbing the png, not the svg. That's speculative, requires testing. Say: <div class="svg-container><div class="png-image"><img src="image.png" alt=""></div><div class="svg-image"><img src="image.svg" alt=""></div></div> where the opacity of .png-image img is 0. Since the css won't transfer on drag, that might work, since the user is actually dragging the transparent png..

Comment: I've used similar tricks in production, for example, to make clickable areas of an image, by putting a transparent div over the area I want clickable, and having a link in that. I'm not putting this as an answer because it would require testing to confirm it works.